# Regular expression in R extracts the part between two matching strings (NOT intendet)

Tags: r, regex, nlp

I am trying to clean some documents in R and extract in text citations. If there are two citations close to each other (with only a few words in between) R extracts the part beween the matching strings as well. It might have something to do with my regex being greedy, but I am not sure how to solve this.

My regex looks like this

```
"\\([.A-Z].*\\,[[:space:]]([0-9]{4}[a-z]?)\\)|\\([.A-Z].*\\,[[:space:]][n.d.].*\\)|\\([.A-Z].*\\,[[:space:]]\\(?forthcoming\\)?\\)|\\([0-9]{4}[a-z]?\\)"
```

This is some example data

```
s <- "Author (Author, 1996), Text"
t <- "Author (Author, 1996a), Text"
r <- "Author (Bla usw, forthcoming), Title Analysis, Paris"
k <- "Author (Author, n.d.), text"
m <- "text (Lara, Bera and Ceta, 2009), I dont want R to grab this part (Whatever, 2003) text goes on"  
n <- "Smthing (Author, forthcoming some other text I do not want extracted because it is not a citation but some random numbers and text 1234) stmth"
n <- "Smthing (Author, forthcoming) stmth"
i <- "Authors or something, A B and C. (2012a), text,"

l <- list(s,t,r, k, m, i,n )
```

To check if it works I used that:

```
regmatches(l, regexpr("\\([.A-Z].*\\,[[:space:]]([0-9]{4}[a-z]?)\\)| \\([.A-Z].*\\,[[:space:]][n.d.].*\\)|\\([.A-Z].*\\,[[:space:]]\\(?forthcoming\\)?\\)|\\([0-9]{4}[a-z]?\\)", l))
```

I only want the part in the parenthesis, but only this (there are more parenthesis in the text, so I cannot just extract those).

So I want it to extract

```
(Author, 1996)
(Author, 1996a)
(Author, n.d.)
(Lara, Bera and Ceta, 2009)
(Whatever, 2003)
(Author, forthcoming)
(2012a)
```

but it currently extracts the middle part in this one string here as well. I want the text in both parenthesis as well as in the other strings, but not the part between them, that says "I dont want R to grab this part".

```
(Lara, Bera and Ceta, 2009), I dont want R to grab this part (Whatever, 2003)
```

How do I prevent that?

Comment: You probably want `str_extract_all(l, "\\([^()]*\\)")`

Comment: Unfortunately this also grabs text in parenthesis that I want in my analysis...

Comment: Maybe `unlist(str_extract_all(l, "\\([^()]*\\b(?:[0-9]{4}[a-z]?|forthcoming|n\\.d\\.)\\)"))`? Do you want `(Bla usw, forthcoming)` or not?

Comment: Nope, I dont want that because it could be some important text (if it grabs the "forthcoming" that is fine, I just wanted to see if I have the word in there what happened.

Comment: I am afraid the question has become too unclear at this point. *What* do you want to match? Provide clear rules.

Comment: The citations which could be (Author, 1234), (Author, 1234a), (Author, forthcoming) and (Author, n.d.).

Comment: What are *citations*? Regex does not have a notion of a "citation". How can you describe the *pattern* you want to find in strings? Look, `(Lara, Bera and Ceta, 2009)` has more than one *author*. Again, regex does not have a notion of "author"

Comment: I mean scientific in text citations. Thats why I tried to find the parenthesis (Words starting with a capital letter, a comma and a year \\([.A-Z].*\\,[[:space:]]([0-9]{4}[a-z]?)\\) OR the same with n.d. if there is no year OR with forthcoming OR just a year followed by a letter in parenthesis. It works pretty fine, it just grabs too sometimes, like in the case of string m, where it grabst the text "I dont want this part" as well.

Comment: That is because matching names is too hacky with regex. I must go now, try `unlist(str_extract_all(l, "\\((?:\\p{Lu}\\w*(?:\\s+\\p{Lu}\\w*)*(?:\\s*(?:and|,)\\s*\\p{Lu}\\w*(?:\\s+\\p{Lu}\\w*)*)*\\s*(?:,\\s*)?)?\\b(?:[0-9]{4}[a-z]?|(?:forthcoming|n\\.d\\.))\\)"))`, see [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/8s7yEt/1).

Comment: This definetly does not catch too much, which works for me! Thank you!

Comment: No idea if I should post it. If you use it and find issues with it, let me know.

Comment: I am using it, if you want, you can post it and i will mark it as answered

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not perfect, but you may use

```
## Input
l <- c("Author (Author, 1996), Text", "Author (Author, 1996a), Text", "Author (Bla usw, forthcoming), Title Analysis, Paris", "Author (Author, n.d.), text", "text (Lara, Bera and Ceta, 2009), I dont want R to grab this part (Whatever, 2003) text goes on", "Authors or something, A B and C. (2012a), text,", "Smthing (Author, forthcoming) stmth")

## Building the regex...
author_rx <- "\\p{Lu}\\w*(?:\\s+\\p{Lu}\\w*)*"
must_have_rx <- "(?:[0-9]{4}[a-z]?|forthcoming|n\\.d\\.)"
regex <- paste0("\\((?:",author_rx,"(?:\\s*(?:and|,)\\s*",author_rx, ")*\\s*(?:,\\s*)?)?\\b",must_have_rx,"\\)")

## Running the regex...
str_extract_all(l, regex)
```

Results:

```
[[1]]
[1] "(Author, 1996)"

[[2]]
[1] "(Author, 1996a)"

[[3]]
character(0)

[[4]]
[1] "(Author, n.d.)"

[[5]]
[1] "(Lara, Bera and Ceta, 2009)" "(Whatever, 2003)"           

[[6]]
[1] "(2012a)"

[[7]]
[1] "(Author, forthcoming)"
```

The regex is

```
\((?:\p{Lu}\w*(?:\s+\p{Lu}\w*)*(?:\s*(?:and|,)\s*\p{Lu}\w*(?:\s+\p{Lu}\w*)*)*\s*(?:,\s*)?)?\b(?:[0-9]{4}[a-z]?|forthcoming|n\.d\.)\)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/8s7yEt/2).

**Details**

- `\(` - `(` char
- `(?:` - start of an optional non-capturing group:

  - `\p{Lu}\w*(?:\s+\p{Lu}\w*)*` - `author_rx`: an uppercase, 0+ word chars, and then 0 or more sequences of 1+ whitespaces, 1 uppercase and 0+ word chars
  - `(?:\s*(?:and|,)\s*\p{Lu}\w*(?:\s+\p{Lu}\w*)*)*` - 0 or more sequences of:

    - `\s*` - 0+ whitespaces
    - `(?:and|,)` - `and` or `,`
    - `\s*` - 0+ whitespaces
    - `\p{Lu}\w*(?:\s+\p{Lu}\w*)*` - `author_rx` pattern (see above)
- `\s*` - 0+ whitespaces
- `(?:,\s*)?` - an optional sequence of `,` and 0+ whitespaces
- `)?` - end of the first non-capturing group
- `\b` - word boundary
- `(?:[0-9]{4}[a-z]?|forthcoming|n\.d\.)` - one of:

  - `[0-9]{4}[a-z]?`  - four digits and an optional lowercase letter
  - `forthcoming` - this word
  - `n\.d\.`  - `n.d.` substring
- `\)` - a `)` char.

Answer (score 1):

For a one-liner solution, we may use `sub` with the following regex pattern:

```
.*?(\\([^)]+\\)).*
```

This says to match and capture the *first* term in parentheses.  Note that the `.*?` is the lazy dot, which tells the regex engine to stop at the first occurrence.

Here is a sample script:

```
m <- "text (Lara, Bera and Ceta, 2009), I dont want R to grab this part (Whatever, 2003) text goes on"
sub(".*?(\\([^)]+\\)).*", "\\1", m)

[1] "(Lara, Bera and Ceta, 2009)"
```

Comment: This just grabs all of the strings in my script.

Comment: Your sample input/output seems to imply that you want to retain the first term, but not second onwards, in parentheses.  If this is not the case, please update your question with the actual problem.

Comment: @H.Stevens Please [edit this demo](https://rextester.com/NOBC85384) and show where the answer is actually failing.

Comment: https://rextester.com/XTE9178  (Sorry if im using this tool wrong, I have never seen it before)

Answer (score 0):

It would be helpful if you show examples of strings in parentheses that you don't want matched but in the absence of that extract all portions within parentheses.  **Then you can grep out from that the ones you want using whatever complex pattern you like without worrying about junk not in parentheses.** (For example, if only the good ones have 4 digits or a comma then apply `grep(",|\\d{4}", s, value = TRUE)` .

```
library(gsubfn)
s <- unlist(strapplyc(unlist(l), "\\([^)]*\\)"))
```

giving the following:

```
> s
[1] "(Author, 1996)"                            
[2] "(Author, 1996a)"                           
[3] "(Bla usw, forthcoming)"                    
[4] "(Author, n.d.)"                            
[5] "(Lara, Bera and Ceta, 2009)"               
[6] "(Whatever, 2003)"                          
[7] "(Author, forthcoming some other text 1234)"
[8] "(Author, forthcoming)"                     
[9] "(2012a)"
```

Comment: [I have already suggested it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57376204/regular-expression-in-r-extracts-the-part-between-two-matching-strings-not-inte?noredirect=1#comment101237903_57376204) and the answer is *Unfortunately this also grabs text in parenthesis that I want in my analysis.*

Comment: The pattern was the same but that solution only extracted the first citation on each line.